# How do I extract the IPv4 IP Addresses from the output of ipconfig, and then filter it so that my output only includes a list of the IP addresses?

Tags: windows-7, networking, cmd.exe, ipconfig, findstr

[How do I extract the IPv4 IP Address from the output of ipconfig](https://superuser.com/questions/1034471/how-do-i-extract-the-ipv4-ip-address-from-the-output-of-ipconfig)

I read through this post and it was very helpful. I was just wondering if the is a way I can extract only the IP Addresses (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx). Best way I could think of using notepad to find all / replace all.

Is there a method that I can use via command line?

Comment: In what way does the question you linked to not provide you with all the information you need?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to be clearer and more complete.

Comment: @G-Man Clearly my answer to the other question gives some clues as to how it might be solved, but needs tweaking to provide the output that the OP wants. Most users are not sufficiently knowledge about batch programming to make those changes. I have provide an answer for the OP which I believe answers his question.

Comment: @G-Man I'm reasonably proficient with batch files, but I still had to think about how to add a regular expression to findstr to match dotted quad ip addresses.

Comment: @DavidPostill:  But my point is, you didn’t need to. The “search for `IPv4` / split on ``:`` / strip leading space” approach works. And aren’t moderators always berating users that “if you find yourself posting substantially the same answer to two separate questions (in the same community), you should stop, and flag one of them as a duplicate instead”?

Comment: @G-Man No it doesn't. That approach only find the **first** dotted quad address (which happens to be a line containing the string IP4). If you actually bothered to read my answer you will see it extracts a list of 3 IP addresses. As for your second point my answer here is substantially **different** from my other answer.

Comment: @G-Man Note the question title asks for a **list** of IP addresses not just the single address labelled IP4.

Comment: And you really should look into powershell.

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I extract only a list of IP4 addresses from the output of ipconfig?

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /r "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*"`) do (
  set _temp=%%a
  rem remove leading space
  set _ipaddress=!_temp:~1!
  echo !_ipaddress!
  )
endlocal
```

Example usage and output:

```
> ipconfig | findstr /r "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*"
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.78
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.129

> test
192.168.42.78
255.255.255.0
192.168.42.129
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [ipconfig](http://ss64.com/nt/ipconfig.html) - Configure IP (Internet Protocol configuration)
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) - Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).

Answer (score 0):

Building on [DavidPostill’s answer to the question you linked to](https://superuser.com/q/1034471/354511#1034600),

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem throw away everything except the IPv4 address line 
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`ipconfig ^| findstr IPv4`) do (
  rem we have for example "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.78"
  rem split on ':' and get 2nd token
  for /f delims^=^:^ tokens^=2 %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
    rem we have " 192.168.42.78"
    rem split on '.' and get 4 tokens (octets)
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%c in ("%%b") do (
      set _o1=%%c
      set _o2=%%d
      set _o3=%%e
      set _o4=%%f
      rem strip leading space from first octet
      set _4octet=!_o1:~1!.!_o2!.!_o3!.!_o4!
      echo !_4octet!
      )
    )
  )
endlocal
```

will ***list*** the IPv4 addresses
for all the interfaces reported by `ipconfig`.